# Sort a linked linked list by name and date of birth

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have ran into some difficulties. I want to adapt this piece of code below to sort a singly linked list of type Person. for example, I have:

```
class Person{
    private String fn = "NN";
    private String ln = "NN";
    private Date dob = new Date(1, 1, 1970);
}
```

I would like to sort the linked list of Persons by firstname, last name and date of birth. At the same time I have been given a piece of code to adapt it but, I can't seem to find a way around it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Here is the code to adapt below:

```
public void sort() {

    TextIO.putln("sorting...");
    if (head == null)
        return;

    Node max, t, out = null, h = new Node();
    h.next = head;

    while (h.next != null) {
        // display(); 
        TextIO.putln("max=" + (max = findmax(h)).next);
        t = max.next;
        max.next = t.next;
        t.next = out;
        out = t;
    }
    head = out;

}

private Node findmax(Node h) {
    char max = '\0';
    Node maxNode = h;
    for (Node tmp = h; tmp.next != null; tmp = tmp.next) {
        if (tmp.next.data.c >= max) {
            max = tmp.next.data.c;
            maxNode = tmp;
        }
    }
    return maxNode;
}
```

If not, a detailed advice will be highly helpful thanks. Mind you, I cannot use collection.sort or any other ready function, it has to be implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like you to look at [this link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html). It will give you idea of how Node class is implemented and generally how to implement list.

Assuming you read content from the link here are some comments;

```java
public void sort() { 
     //this method does ascending sort of the list

     TextIO.putln("sorting..."); 
     if (head == null) 
         return; 

     Node max, t, out = null, h = new Node(); 
     h.next=head; //make new list node let him point to beginning of the list(head)

     while (h.next != null) { //until we get to the end of the list
         // display(); 

         TextIO.putln("max="+(max = findmax(h)).next);
         //after findmax is finished we know reference
         //to the node that contains max value
         //and we need to bring that node to the beginning of the list
         //that requires some reference rewiring
         //first set t to point to next node from max
         t = max.next;
         //than max node will point to the next node from t
         //this way max node becomes detached from list
         max.next = t.next;
         // now max node will point to some node that will represent new list head
         // not new list just new list head
         t.next = out; 
         out = t; 
     } 
     //after we complete sorting just point list head to the sorted list
     head = out; 

 } 

 //find node that contains max value starting from some node   
 private Node findmax(Node h) { 
     //declare that max is null char
     char max = '\0'; 
     // set maxNode to be current node
     Node maxNode = h; 
     //go through all nodes starting from current which is h
     for (Node tmp = h; tmp.next != null; tmp = tmp.next) { 
         //if the data of some node in the list is bigger then our max value
         if (tmp.next.data.c >= max) {
             //then we are going to set that new value to be max 
             max = tmp.next.data.c;
             // and set maxNode to be the node that has max value
             maxNode = tmp; 
         } 
     } 
     return maxNode; 
 }
```

My advice is to look at provided link and start using good old pen an paper. That is the best way to understand what is going on with list pointers and nodes.
But if you do not want pen and paper you could go to [this link](http://www.csanimated.com/animation.php?t=Linked_list) that will show you animation of basic list operations.